# Inverse Trigonometric Functions and Summation of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am aware that these types of questions are dealt with by the properties of $\tan^{-1} x_r-\tan^{-1} x_{r-1}$ but here I am not able to proceed by that approach...PLEASE HELP!

$$
\sum_{r=1}^\infty\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2r}{1-r^2+r^4}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\frac{2n}{1+n^2-n^4}=\frac{n(n+1)-n(n-1)}{1+[n(n+1)][n(n-1)]}
$$
So
$$
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2n}{1+n^2-n^4}\right)=\tan^{-1}n(n+1)-\tan^{-1}n(n-1)
$$
and thus you have a telescoping sum.